# How to reset 2 or more forms in HTML?

Tags: html

Is it possible to do this without using any CSS or Javascript functions? Here is the code:

```
<table align="center"> <tr> <td>
<form>
<a style="font-size:14px"> <b>Input1:</b> </a> <input type="text" size="51"> <br> <br>
<a style="font-size:14px"> <b>Select1:</b> </a> <br> <br>
<input type="radio" name="qwe" value="qwer">Choice1<br>
<input type="radio" name="qwe" value="qwer">Choice2<br> <br>
</form>
<form>
<a style="font-size:14px"> <b>Select2:</b> </a> <br> <br>
<input type="radio" name="qwe" value="qwer">Choice1<br>
<input type="radio" name="qwe" value="qwer">Choice2<br> <br>
<a style="font-size:14px"> <b>Input2: </b> </a> <input type="text" size="38"> <br><br>
<a style="font-size:14px"> <b>Input3: </b> </a> <input type="text" size="31"> <br><br>
<input type="reset" style="background-color:#666; border:4; border-color:#000; color:#FFF" value="Delete" >
</form>
</td> </tr> </table>
```

As you can see, there are 2 independent forms but when I hit "Delete" button it resets only the last form. So, I need your help. Regards.

Comment: because I have 2 different choices (selections)

Comment: You only need one `form`. A form is used for a set of values posted/"get"ed to a specific URL.

Comment: I've solved the problem with one form, it seems good now.. the declaration of input type is the one that matters.. for example, I've set up name="selection1" for first two and name="selection2" for last two choices..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have at least one `input type="reset"` per form if you don't want JS to be involved.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, because it makes no sense if I would have 2 reset buttons on page ;) how about using <div> tags ?